# Check whether the sequence is a subsequence of another

Tags: c#

There are two sequences of numbers. Check whether the second sequence is a subsequence of the first sequence. The sequence B[0], ... , B[m] is a subsequence of the sequence A[0], ... , A[n], if there exist numbers 0≤ i_0< i_1< ...< i_m≤n such that for all k  from 0 to m one has B[k]=A[i_k].

Input:

An array of integers:

1. Quantity of the members of the first sequence.
2. Members of the first sequence.
3. Quantity of the members of the second sequence.
4. Members of the second sequence.

Output:

An integer:

·        Either one if the second sequence is a subsequence of the first sequence,

·        Or zero if not.

My solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        var numbers = input.Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
        int a = numbers[0];
        int[] arr1 = numbers.Skip(1).Take(a).ToArray();
        int b = numbers.Skip(a + 1).Take(1).ToArray()[0];
        int[] arr2 = numbers.Skip(a + 2).Take(b).ToArray();
        if(arr1.Length==0 || arr2.Length==0) Console.Write("0");
        else Console.Write(contains(arr1, arr2));
    }

    private static int contains(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {
        int check = 1;
        int[] checkArray = arr1;
        for(int i=0;i<arr2.Length;i++)
        {
            if (!checkArray.Contains(arr2[i])) return 0;
            checkArray = checkArray.Skip(Array.FindIndex(checkArray, x => x==arr2[i])).ToArray();
        }
        return check;
    }
```

It runs on automatic tester, and returns correct result on every teste except a single one. I don't know what is input data for this test, and i can't find it out. What can cause such problem and what would be solution for it?

UPD: Examples from the description of the task
Examples:

Input: 5 1 2 3 4 5 2 1 4

Output: 1

Input: 5 1 2 3 4 5 2 4 1

Output: 0

Answer (score 0):

This returns 1 : 3 1 2 3 3 1 1 3

1. First array length: 3
2. First array: 1 2 3
3. Second array length: 3
4. Second array: 1 1 3

The second array should not be a subsequence by your definition. I think the reason is `FindIndex` returns a 0 based index, so you `Skip` should add 1 to the returned value to skip the correct number.

You also don't need to do both a `Contains` and a `FindIndex`. `FindIndex` returns -1 if index is not there and that prevents unnecessarily iterations over the array. It also has an overload that takes the range to search in so you don't need to use `skip` And `take`. See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: According to the description, elements in subsequence don't have to be in consecutive positions in the first array. Here are examples, provided with the description: 
  
Input:
5 1 2 3 4 5 2 1 4 
Output:
1 
  
Input:
5 1 2 3 4 5 2 4 1 
Output:
0

Comment: Ah my bad. I assumed subsequence meant in order. What did you mean by this bit "there exist numbers 0≤ i_0"?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Looks like i accidentally removed a part of text while editing the original post, now it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

oh! i had the same problem)) i found solution! its correct version on c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int len, len2, t=0, i=0;

    std::string sentence;
    std::cout.flush();

    std::getline(std::cin,sentence);
    std::istringstream iss(sentence);

    std::vector<double> words;
    std::vector<double> SubSeq;

    vector<double>::iterator it;
    double word;
    while(iss >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
    len= static_cast<int>(words.front());
    it = words.begin();
    words.erase(it);
    words.shrink_to_fit();

    for( i=len; i<words.size(); i++ )
    {
           SubSeq.insert(SubSeq.end(),words[i]);
    }
    it = words.begin()+len;
    words.erase(it,words.end());
    words.shrink_to_fit();


    len2= static_cast<int>(SubSeq.front());
    it = SubSeq.begin();
    SubSeq.erase(it);
    SubSeq.shrink_to_fit();

    int j;
    for(i=0 , j=0; i<len && j<len2; i++ )
    {
        if( SubSeq[j]== words[i]){
            j++;
        }
    }

    if( j == len2)
        cout<<1;
    else
        cout<<0;
  return 0;
}
```

i change this part

```
/*
 i=0;
        for(it=words.begin(); it!=words.end(); it++ )
        {
            if( SubSeq[i]== *it){
                i++;    
        }
*/
```

and paste this

```
for(i=0 , j=0; i<len && j<len2; i++ )
        {
            if( SubSeq[j]== words[i]){
                j++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The core logic of this problem is to look forward through both sequences. As you find an instance of the next element in the first sequence in the second, you can advance in the first. The critical step that you're missing is that when you find a match, you need to "consume" the element of the second by incrementing its iterator.

```
checkArray = checkArray.Skip(Array.FindIndex(checkArray, x => x==arr2[i])).ToArray();
```

This line won't change the contents of `checkArray` when `FindIndex` returns 0, so you can keep matching on the first element. As a result, your algorithm will report that "2 2 2 2" is a substring of "1 2 3".

I'm generally a fan of the Linq extensions, but I think it really obfuscates the code here. I would just write a loop to process the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with for Loop

```
import java.util.*;

class Program {
  public static boolean isValidSubsequence(List<Integer> array, List<Integer> sequence) {
    // Write your code here.
    int k=0;
    if(array.equals(sequence)){
      return true;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
      if(k!=sequence.size() && array.get(i)==sequence.get(k)){
        k=k+1;
      }
    }
    if(k==sequence.size())
       return true;
    
    return  false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> It runs on automatic tester, and returns correct result on every teste except a single one.

I agree with the statement in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496186/check-whether-the-sequence-is-a-subsequence-of-another#answer-54496430), regarding expecting input `3 1 2 3 3 1 1 3` to output `0`. This may be the reason for the failing test case.

Another possible scenario is that the automatic tester performs a test where the subsequence is empty. Your implementation would return `0`, whereas the automatic tester may expect `1`.

Regardless of the reason for the failing test case, I would suggest that your helper method

- handles *all* possible cases (i.e. dropping the `if`/`else` condition in `Main()`)
- iterates over the *source* sequence rather than the *subsequence*, to determine whether the former contains the latter

  - by defining an index variable for the subsequence outside the loop that iterates over the source sequence, you can conditionally update that index variable inside the loop

A possible implementation of the helper method could be:

```csharp
public static int Contains(this int[] source, int[] subsequence)
{
    if (subsequence.Length == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (source.Length < subsequence.Length)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    var subindex = 0;
    
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (item != subsequence[subindex])
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        subindex++;
        
        if (subindex == subsequence.Length)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The helper method may be used in your `Main()` as follows:

```
var firstSequenceContainsSecondSequence = arr1.Contains(arr2);
```

Example fiddle (without any input verification) [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qfvd8H).